# How can I change the default output folder path of the GO file?

Tags: go, goland

Because I had installed the Avira in my computer, once I run my go file in [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/), Avira will prompt me a security alert that  "BLOCK HEUR/APC(could) ........."

Meanwhile, GoLand also shows that

> Error running 'go build test.go': Cannot run program "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp___2go_build_test_go.exe" (in directory "E:\Application software\GO\awesomeProject"): CreateProcess error=5, ACCESS DENIED.

I want to know how can I change the default output path (i.e., build -o "path") to another path; after all, I don't want to close the realtime protection of Avira in each time, and ‘C’ disk is also a sensitive area. Should I configure the settings of the GO source or just change some settings in GoLand? B.T.W, unless necessary, I don't want to change the settings of Avira :)

Thanks in advance, I am a beginner of Go language.

Comment: probably try to run the GoLand as administrator

Comment: There is no need to run GoLand as an administrator. Even if the compiled application would require administrative rights, then you can enable the `Run with elevated priviledges` checkbox in the Run Configuration settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the run configuration via `Run | Edit Configurations...` and set the `Output directory` to whatever location you'd like to, see the screenshot below.

[image: outpud directory in a run configuration]

If you wish to set this for all new run configurations of the project, then go to `Run | Edit Configurations... | Templates | Go Build` and then configure the `Output directory` setting there. All new `Go Build` configurations will then use that setting.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!